# Blobs/Goop that block extruder in prints

Tags: ultimaker-cura, flashforge-adventurer-4

Sorry if this is something obvious, as I am new to 3D Printing and could not figure out why this is happening.

Just switched to Cura from Simply3D as well as initially from FlashPrint as I wanted to be able to do more advanced stuff, which Cura provides (i.e. different infills per area via support blockers, etc...).

I tried matching the settings from S3D and FP as close as possible, but I am missing something. The same STL prints fine with S3D and FP [same PLA and Temps], but when I slice it with Cura, I sometimes get random blobs that expand around the extruder and stop the print. Is there some setting I am doing wrong?

Any help with what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Photo of a partially printed models with blobs in them]

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Does the printer stop and extrude to produce the blob or is it accumulated during printing until it reaches a point and gets stuck? It looks as if the printer stopped moving and extruded the blob at once. Please explain by [edit].

Comment: Not sure; it works for a few hours, then does it. I will put a camera on the next print I do and record the process.

Comment: Printing via Sd Card ? or with USB cable? I have seen my flashforge printers do something like this while printing with USB Cable connected from laptop. Is there cura project that we can take a look at it? If s3d can able to print, thats because you have chosen right firmware, but in cura have you done same? Sharing some more info will help us to debug on why its happening with cura.

Comment: I think it was USB, I now copy to local storage, and stuff works better. TY for the help.